# Started seeing object heap exceptions Java 6

Tags: java, ant, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I've started seeing the following error using 32-bit (and 64 for that matter) Java 6 (on Windows 8 x64. This wasn't an issue until some Windows updates were installed.....) to call ant scripts

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Anyone ever seen it before? I've done some digging around SO and other places and haven't come across anything that's solved this issue for

**Edit 8/24**

So far, here are the following things I have attempted to fix the issue, none of which have worked:

1. Setting `_JAVA_OPTIONS` in system environment variables, up to 3gb for the maximum heap size
2. Setting `JVM_OPTS` in `cmd` before invoking ant, again max heap size up to 3gb
3. Passing in `-Xms` and `-Xmx` arguments when making the actual java call, like so `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java  -Xms512m -Xmx2048m org.apache.tools.ant.Main`
4. Setting the `ANT_OPTS` variable before calling ant
5. Uninstalling Windows updates going back before these issues.

   Does anyone have a solution that differs from the following? As the other attempts have not been working..

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Could+not+reserve+enough+space+for+object+heap . Though this is more likely to be virtual memory size relatied

Comment: Yeah I've tried that lol

Comment: Always gotta try to find the answer yourself being asking on SO (;

Answer (score 1):

When you run on 32-bit windows (or in the 32-bit windows emulator) you have only about 1.2 GB - 1.5 GB of virtual memory available.  This size depends on what else you might have running in that space as it doesn't always isolate programs from each other in terms of memory space (i.e. the memory space is limit and shared)

So after updating windows, it could have installed a new program which is run before Java, or updated an existing which is using more memory.

The simplest solution is to use a 64-bit JVM which doesn't have this problem. Or you have to reduce the maximum heap size.

Comment: Should have clarified. This is x64 Windows

Comment: @AndrewSmiley if you run a 32-bit process, it runs in the 32-bit Windows XP emulator.  i.e. it tries very hard to work the same way as Win XP with it's limitations.

Comment: I've run into this issue with both 32 and 64 bit JVMs

Comment: @AndrewSmiley If you are running the 64-bit JVM and you are asking for a modest amount of memory e.g. 1 GB this means you are very low on free memory.  How much free memory and free swap space do you have?

Comment: Using around 6.5gb of 16 available

Comment: @AndrewSmiley That should be enough, are you sure you are running the 64-bit version?

Comment: Yes sir. That's what I thought too. Oddly enough, this was happening when nothing but the ant build was going too